# Problem with AR development in Unity WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, unity-webgl

I'm using Zappar Plugin with Universal AR to develop an application with Unity that runs as a WebGL. I'm currently using Zappar Image Tracker to track a QR code, when pointed, a mesh appears. The problem is when I stop pointing to QR code, the mesh disappears. Has anyone ever used this plugin and know how can I do that?

Comment: did it say it was webGL compatible?

Comment: Yes, this plugin is used for it. I've already have an application working in WebGL. My problem is when I stop poiting to the target, the mesh disappears, and I'm begginer with C#, so I can´t find where I can change it or even if i'ts possible. When I play my application, it seems the anchor of the scene changes when the image target is pointed or not, so I want to keep this anchor after I point once to the target and point elsewhere.